# White space on the right when using bar Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using the below code to save a figure:

```
fig1=figure('visible','off');
b = bar(bar_res);
x={'a' ;'b' ;'c'; 'd' ;'e'; 'f' ;'g'; 'h';...
     'i'; 'j' ;'k'; 'l'; 'm'; 'n' ;'o'; 'p' ;'q' ;'r'; 's';...
     't';'u'};
set(gca,'XTickLabel',x,'XTick',1:21);
rotateXLabels( gca, 90 );
with=char('Res with dash');
without=char('Res without dash');
legend('Reference',with,without,'Location','northwest');
set(gca,'FontSize',16);
y=ylabel('Number of trials','rot',90,'FontSize',18);
set(y,'Units','Normalized','Position',[-0.15, 0.5, 0]);
savefig('a.fig');
saveas(gca, 'a.png');
```

But I don't know why there is extra white space to the right as shown in the below figure:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what `bar_res` look like so that we can reproduce the issue? It might just be a matter of setting the x axis limits, e.g. `xlim([0 21])`.

Comment: Is that margin there in the Matlab plot or is it only present in the saved image?

Comment: @thewaywewalk no, my question is different. The other question is about the white space when saving the fig to pdf, I already know that problem. But in my case the problem is the white space which I highlighted in red in my question in the image.

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes it is in both the Matlab figure plot and the saved image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the **x-limits** with `xlim`:

```
set(gca,'XLim',[0 numel(x)+1]);
```

Example:

```
fig1 = figure('visible','on');
b = bar(randi(10,21,1).');
x = {'a' ;'b' ;'c'; 'd' ;'e'; 'f' ;'g'; 'h';...
     'i'; 'j' ;'k'; 'l'; 'm'; 'n' ;'o'; 'p' ;'q' ;'r'; 's';...
     't';'u'};
set(gca,'XTick',1:21);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',x);
set(gca,'XLim',[0 numel(x)+1]);
% rotateXLabels( gca, 90 );
with = char('Res with dash');
without = char('Res without dash');
legend('Reference',with,without,'Location','northwest');
set(gca,'FontSize',16);
y = ylabel('Number of trials','rot',90,'FontSize',18);
```

[image]

By the way, if you have **Matlab R2014b** or higher you don't need `rotateXLabels` anymore. Just use:

```
ax = gca;
ax.XTickLabelRotation = 90;
```

Comment: Another quick question please. Do you know how to make the text in the legend be only one line? Like in my case there are three words and I have  two values in the legend so the legend height becomes four lines. And I want to make it only two lines (one each). I posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776543/force-legend-in-matlab-figure-to-be-only-one-line-per-value

Comment: @shepherd something like `legend('orientation','horizontal')` will do.

Comment: This changed the legend to be beside each other instead on top of each other. But the text is still on two lines. I think may be it is related to the legend box width and height?

Comment: please post a new question regarding this and we will solve it. Because it is now, I can't even reproduce the problem. Please post a minimal example in the new question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution may be if you call `axis tight`. However it may not be the result you want because it does remove the small spaces at the borders of the plot.