# Force Legend in Matlab Figure to be only one line per value

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm wondering how I can force the text in the legend be only on one line? Like in my case there are three words and I have two values in the legend so the legend height becomes four lines. And I want to make it only two lines (one each). If anyone could please advise.

Comment: In Matlab 2014b, something as long as `legend('one two three four five six seven eight nine ten', 'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten')` does get printed in one line (the legend box becomes very wide, more than half the x-axis width)

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm using Matlab 2015 and it is printed in two lines.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused, I'm using 2015 too (I have 2014b in another computer). And `plot(1:9), hold all, plot(2:9), legend('one two three four five six seven eight nine ten', 'one two three four five')` gives me one line per legend entry (two lines in total)

Comment: yeah it worked now :/

Comment: @LuisMendo shall I delete my question?

Comment: If the problem has disappeared, I guess so. If you can reproduce the problem, edit the question posting some code that generates that issue, so we can work on that

Comment: @LuisMendo I was working on the same code on Matlab 2010 may be that was the problem. As I mixed it with Matlab 2015 as I have both on my machine. Could you post your comment as an answer to accept it?

Comment: Done! But in Matlab 2010b I also get one line per entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab 2010b and in 2015a, a legend as long as

```
plot(1:8)
hold all
plot(2:9)
legend('one two three four five six seven eight nine ten', ...
       'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten')
```

gives one line per legend entry (two lines in total). See attached figures.

[image]

[image]